# What is a alternative to HTTP uploads to upload files?

Tags: php, html, file-upload, upload, host

My host puts a limit on the size of file you can upload through a form to a folder. I want to upload files through FTP in the form of a HTML form. How would I upload a file from a users PC to the FTP server with a HTML form?

Comment: Browser will not do that.  Get a better host.

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but I'd check your hosts Terms of Service to make sure visitor uploaded content is allowed.
Also, even if you allow for larger file uploads, you still may run into the problem of MAX_EXECUTION_TIME.

Comment: @SLaks Do all shared hosts put a max file limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to upload files to ftp. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php